# Merge issue for updating Android Studio from 0.5.1 to 0.5.2

Tags: android-studio

Can't update to AS 0.5.2 from AS 0.5.1.
Got some merge issues...
When I start studio again the system remains on 0.5.1.

Any ideas?

[image: Merge issue]

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue based on this post (https://plus.google.com/+PiyushAgarwal/posts/M1kgHtvBXnt)

Just need to run Android Studio as Administrator.